# My char array in my c++ program will not print anything

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, char

I am doing my first C++ program for my class. I am really new to this program so I have a lot to learn. In my program I am suppose to create a Student class with Undergrad/grad/gradassist derived classes. The name and SSN fields have to be in a char array (I know string makes more sense but the teacher demands a char array). The program mostly works fine except it does not print anything in my char arrays. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;
class Student {
  protected:
    char name[21];
    char ssn[10];
    float gpa;
    int credits;

  public: 
     Student::Student() {};

     Student(const char n[], const char ss[], float& gp, int& cred) {
      name[21] = n[21];
      ssn[10] = ss[10];
      gpa = gp;
      credits = cred;


  }

    virtual void print() {
     cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
     cout << "SSN: " << ssn << endl;
     cout << "GPA: " << gpa << endl;
     cout << "Credits: " << credits << endl;
 }
    virtual float tuition() const = 0;


 };
class undergrad : public Student {
  protected:
    float undergrad_rate;
    char* year;
  public:
   undergrad::undergrad() {}

   undergrad(float ugr, char* yr, const char n[], const char ss[], float& 
   gp, int& cred) :
   Student(n, ss, gp, cred), undergrad_rate(ugr), year(yr){}

   void set_year(char* yr) {
    year = yr;
                            }
   char* getYear() {
    return year;
      }
   float getRate() {
    return undergrad_rate;
      }
    void print() {
    Student::print();
    cout << "Undergrad rate: " << undergrad_rate << endl;
    cout << "year: " << year << endl;


       }

   float tuition() { 
   //cout << "The tuition is $35000" << endl;
   return 35000;
    }

  };
 class grad : public Student {
  protected:
   float grad_rate;
   char* thesis;

  public:

 };

  int main(){

    char* jr = "Junior";
    char* sr1 = "Senior";
    char* fr = "Freshman";
    char* sr = "Sophmore";

    undergrad g(380, jr, "M", "000111222", 4.0, 12);
    g.print();


    system("pause");
    return 0;

 }
```

Comment: `name[21] = n[21]` -> `strcpy(name, n)`

Comment: `name[21] = n[21];` This doesnt do what you think it does, *and* access outside both of these arrays. Also please use std::string instead of char[].

Comment: *I know string makes more sense but the teacher demands a char array* -- Get another teacher as you're learning `C` with a couple of C++ syntax thrown in, not C++.

Comment: _Student class with Undergrad/grad/gradassist base classes._ did you mean derived classes ?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here, in the way you initialize the members *name* and *ssn*:

```
 Student(const char n[], const char ss[], float& gp, int& cred) {
      name[21] = n[21];
      ssn[10] = ss[10];
```

There's more than one thing wrong here

1. *name* and *ssn* are char arrays of size 21 and size 10 respectively. This means that valid indices range from 0 to 20 and 0 to 9 respectively. So by accessing *name[21]* and *ssn[10]* you're accessing elements past the end of the allotted memory.
2. Even if the indices were valid, you would just be assigning a single character by doing it this way.

In order to initialize these member variables the way you're intending, do this:

```
 Student(const char n[], const char ss[], float& gp, int& cred) {
      strcpy_s(name, sizeof(name), n);
      strcpy_s(ssn, sizeof(ssn), ss);
```

This will copy all the characters comprising the input strings into your member variables and you will get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you!! You saved our life!